# What is the jazz music used in the OptiCorner commercial on YouTube?

Tags: identify-this-song, jazz

can somebody recognize this [song](https://www.youtube.com/watch?v=m_Tl1_cBKfs)?

[image]

Answer (score 4, accepted):

**Floaters - Jimmy Fontanez/Media Right Productions**

https://www.youtube.com/watch?v=C9lMKLpmRUg

Answer (score 1):

That is generic "[smooth jazz](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Smooth_jazz)" with a random piece of electronica inserted.  Smooth jazz is frequently criticized by jazz purists as being inoffensive, commercialized pap, and is often used in advertisements, perhaps because of its supposed blandness.  This particular piece is almost certainly "library music," created specifically for commercial use, and not a specific song ever released to the general public.

If you'd like to hear the kind of music that inspired this particular track, look up musician [Kenny G](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Kenny_G).